# Effect of clemmensen reagent on 4-oxo-4-phenylbutanoic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-reduction

When I first solved the question, I had reduced the ketonic group. Then as the medium is acidic the -OH in carboxylic acid, will get protonated and there will be formation of stable carbocation and it will attach to the benzene ring. I hope you get it. But in the answer, the carboxylic acid retained and only ketonic group is reduced. Please help.

Comment: Clemmensen is done in cHCl, but this is not the dehydrating conditions necessary to create the carbonyl cation necessary to give cyclisation as there is still a lot of water present. You need something like polyphosphoric acid.

Comment: Then for the compound  3-hydroxycyclopentanone on applying same reagent, the answer given is  chlorocyclopentane. Then how is that it possible?

Comment: Secondary alcohol in cHCl which is stable. You're protonating an alcohol not an acid and you have a better nucleophile present in chloride. If you produced an acyl chloride under Clemmensen conditions it would just hydrolyse back to the acid.

Comment: How can u say H2O is a better nucleophile than cl-. As charged molecules are always better nucleophile than neutral. Also on second attempt is think after formation of ring the acidic group is now converted into a keto group so I think it would also get reduced. So I think it is a special case in which  carboxylic acids will get reduced. Please help where am I wrong.